# Iptables to forward traffic betwen two tunnels

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, iptables

I'm trying to forward some traffic from one OpenVPN client instance to another. [as pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAxyS.jpg)

I want to forward traffic from some ports and keep others on the VPN1 instance.

All the rules I'm applying are in VPN1, as the client doesn't have to care if its traffic gets forwarded and, also, the the VPN2 doesn't have to care "who" asked the request. So, here are the rules I'm using right on the VPN1 instance:

To the client how that it can reach 10.8.0.0/24 network, I addedOn the `server.conf` file I added:

```
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

In order to forward traffic from `tun0` to `tun1` I add the following rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT     #forward traffic
```

In order to get internet connection on the first tunnel, I also have:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

So, here is where I'm starting to fail. Following [this link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html), I added the following:

```
echo "1 nextHop" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun1 table nextHop
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x1 lookup nextHop
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1  ## or whatever port I want to forward.
```

When I add the last iptables rule, traffic goes from `tun0` on the client, to `tun0` on the VPN1, to `tun1` on VPN1, to `tun0` on VPN2 and reaches the internet. However, the reply is getting to `tun0` on VPN2 and redirected to `tun1` on VPN1, but IT IS NOT BEING FORWARDED to `tun0` on VPN1, in order to reach `tun0` on the client. I saw that with `tcpdump`.

I've tried many different approaches as using `DNAT` and `SNAT` but I'm still not able to get the reply forwarded back to the client.

How can I forward some ports from VPN1 to VPN2 and get the replies back to the client?

Comment: Why do you think you need masquerading (and therefore `iptables`) to connect the two VPN tunnels? You can just enable forwarding, that shold be sufficient. You just have to be careful with your routes (and the automatic route setup of OpenVPN) so the "outer" tunnel connection doesn't get forwarded.

Comment: Because I don't want to forward ALL the traffic, just some ports. Therefore, I think that I need `iptables`. And I think that I need masquerading, because the traffic from the client won't go to the outer VPN if I don't, will it?